# nginx not redirecting to tomcat

Tags: nginx, tomcat8

I am using nginx server (nginx version: nginx/1.10.0 (Ubuntu))
created a Tomcat 8 configuration in `/etc/nginx/conf.d/tomcat.conf`

```
server {
  listen          80;
  root            /opt/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/;
   server_name mysite.com;
   server_name_in_redirect off;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/site/site_access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/site/site_error.log debug;

  location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_cookie_path ~*^/.* /;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
  }
}
```

`www.site.com` is showing Welcome to  nginx and my tomcat project is showing on `http://ip:8080`.

Problem is `www.site.com` is not redirecting to 8080

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't defined a host `www.mysite.com`, at least not in the config stanza you showed, but there appears to be an additional `server {}` section in another file that handles `www,mysite.com`. You need to disable that and add `www.mysite.com` to the section you showed:

```
server_name mysite.com www.mysite.com;
```

Comment: I am using same configuration in another server but this is working how?

Comment: @xrcwrn: I don't understand this comment.

Comment: Your answer is working properly.

Comment: I am using my above code that is working on my another server??

Comment: The other parts of your other server configuration are different, that is why it works in a different way.